# How do I merge two lists together into a dictionary in Python? Dict and Zip aren't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, zip

I have two lists - "A" and "B" that have 3,158 elements in each. I'm trying to merge the two lists into a dictionary, but dict(zip()) isn't working. Here's the layout for my original Excel file (here are three data points for an example):

```
    Name     ExecConsumer
    Report1   John
    Report2   Brian
    Report3   Mike
```

I imported the data using pandas. There are about 20 columns in the Excel file, so I extracted two separate columns from the file and assigned them to variables. The defined DataFrame is df100. Here's the code:

```
    AE=df100.loc[:,["ExecConsumer"]]
    ReportNames=df100.loc[:,"Name"]]
    RT = dict(zip(ReportNames,AE))
```

Here's my output:

```
    {"ExecConsumer":"Name"}
```

I was expecting:

```
    {"Report1":"John", "Report2":"Brian", "Report3":"Mike", ....}
```

Thoughts? If I print both AE and ReportName separately, they are not empty. But the moment I merge them, I'm not getting what I expect. I'm using Python 3.7 if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: `df.loc()` finds rows by lable in an indexing manner and it seems that in `df100.loc[:,["ExecConsumer"]]` you're just choosing one `row` and that's why the `zip` ends up with one items. If you want to choose a column you should use a direct indexing on your dataframe.

Comment: If you think you know what's in those two list variables, the first thing to do is print them out to make sure your'e right, and the second thing to do is to use them to write a [mcve] that just starts with "I have these two (trimmed-down) lists…" (and only mentions the CSV, Pandas, etc. stuff at the end, for context).

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]}) ; dict(zip(df.loc[:,'a'], df.loc[:,'b']))` ... works for me.

Comment: @Kasramvd - thanks! I don't know why I didn't realize that I could choose one column just by indexing. I've revised my code to do just that and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
RT = dict(zip(df.loc[:,'Name'],df.loc[:,"ExecConsumer"]))
```

Probably something to do with how python passes everything by value.